# react-Native css styling with multiple arguments

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

how to style in react-native css like this?
border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px

I've tried:
borderWidth:{5,5,5,5}  and
borderWidth:'5px 5px 5px 5px'
but no luck

Answer (score 1):

In `react-native` you cannot use `border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px`. Instead of that you have to use following properties.

```
 1. borderTopWidth, 
 2. borderBottomWidth,  
 3. borderLeftWidth
 4. borderRightWidth
```

But if you want implement some thing like `borderWidth` then you can write your own function.

```
function borderWidth(top,right,bottom,left){
  let styles;
  styles['borderTopWidth'] = top
  styles['borderRightWidth'] = right
  return styles
}
```

then in `Stylesheet` you can use it

```
container : {
    ...borderWidth(5,5,5,5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`borderBottomWidth:5`
`borderTopWidth:5`

etc.

Comment: darns thanks. so this question was actually hoping to answer a bigger one. Im trying to use styling like transform: translate(x,y)    how would one do that?

Comment: Check out the react native docs here: [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms).  `transform([{ skewX: '45deg' }]);`